# Pharo initialize an object with an OrderedCollection

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Indeed it is within the framework of a research. I'm trying to generate random values ​​for the instance variables of an X object. So when instantiating the object, I replace the parameters of the object initialization method with the values ​​that are generated.

So, I manage to retrieve instance variables, generate random values. The problem now is how to replace the arguments of the initialization method with the generated values?

we have my Person class

```
Object subclass: #Person
    instanceVariableNames: 'name lastName birthDate'
    classVariableNames: ''
    package: 'Moi'
```

the method that i use to initialize a person is:

```
withName: aName andBirthDate: aBirthDate andLastName: aLastName
    name:= aName.
    lastName:= aLastName.
    birthDate:= aBirthDate
```

For example I have the method

```
Person>>#withName:aName andBirthDate:aBirthDate andLastName:aLasatName
```

and I have the following values:
"toto", "13 sept 2022" and "tata"

How to override or rebuild method like this

````
Person>>#withName:'toto' andBirthDate:'13 Sep 2022'andLastName:'tata'?
```bri

the Person class is an example. Instead of the Person class, we can have Point, Car or any other class.
````

Answer (score 1):

No, you will need to call the constructor and break out the arguments:

```
Person
  withName: (list at: 1)
  lastName: (list at: 2)
  birthDay: (list at: 3)
```

Comment: Yes it is exact. How Can i do that

Comment: @MansourFaouziel James just showed you how. You need to follow his answer.

Comment: I don't understand where you are coming from

Comment: @MansourFaouziel James just showed you how to call Person Class with a "constructor" `#withName:lastName:birthDay`, which you have place in the class part of the Class Person.

Comment: in fact, my goal is to do something generic. that I can create a new object without knowing the number of parameters to initialize the class.

Comment: The Class Person IS an example. I Can have another class like Class Cours where when you want to initialize this class, i use for example:.  Cours class>>newCours:aName duration:aDuration start:dateStart end:dateEnd.

Comment: While you could loop over the list and use `#'instVarAt:put:` on the object, that would be extremely low-level and is generally frowned upon. It is extremely likely that whatever you are trying to do would be better done another way.

Comment: Hi @JamesFoster, Okay I see. Please do you have another way to do this? according to the description of the problem.

Comment: No, I don't think I can give you any other ideas right now. Perhaps you could describe what you are trying to do. Is this an assignment for school? Or do you have a larger problem that you are trying to solve? What drew you to using Pharo?